# Using Entity Framework with abstract classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, abstract-class

Have a very interesting situation and can't seem to find anything concrete on the webs surrounding reflection, inheritance and generics.

To start off with:

I have a base abstract classed, called:

```
public abstract class ItemBase
{
     // default properties
}
```

ItemBase then becomes my super-class to an abstract entity called Item:

```
public abstract class Item
{
    // some extra properties
}
```

The idea behind this is to construct entities that will inherit from Item with additional properties set:

```
public partial class City : Item {}
```

Now, in a test method I'm trying to use reflection to invoke a method on the passed entity and return whatever data, in what ever form, back from the method.

Assuming, for testing purposes we have a method in State, that returns a collection of all major cities:

```
public List<City> GetAllMajorCities() {}
```

In my stubs I might have a test to get all cities:

```
List<Item> cities = this.InvokeGenericMethod<Item>("State", "GetAllMajorCities", args);
```

Then the InvokeGenericMethod(string, string, object[] args) looks something like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> InvokeGenericMethod<Item>(string className, string methodName, object[] args)
{
     Type classType = className.GetType(); // to get the class to create an instance of
     object classObj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
     object ret = classType.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, classObj, args);
}
```

In theory, from the example given, the value of "ret" should be a type of IEnumerable, however, the returning type, if added to a watch to investivage, return List, if I check the ret value as:

```
if (ret is IEnumerable<T>)
```

it ignores the check.

If I change

```
public List<City> GetAllMajorCities() {}
```

to

```
public List<ItemBase> GetAllMajorCities() {}
```

It seems to adhere to the inheritance and allow me to cast it to IEnumberable.

I'm completely stumped here.

Any ideas, recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Can you please recheck your code? I think there a things mixed up. I guess your InvokeGenericMethod will not work. className.GetType() will allways return type string, for example.

Comment: Hi Achim, the code above is an example of the actual apologies if it's a bit confusing. I use reflection to the the full name of the class, namespace of the class in string format when binding a drop down list, this is then passed, as a string to my InvokeGenericMethod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you are using Framework 3.5? Generic co- and contravariance was introduced in .net 4.0. Thus, the following is not possible in Framework 3.5:

```
class ItemBase { }
class Item : ItemBase { }
class City : Item { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<City> cities = new List<City>();
        IEnumerable<Item> items = cities;  // Compile error here. IEnumerable<Item> is not a supertype of IEnumerable<City>.
    }
}
```

Note that the following (which is what you are trying to achieve) won't even work in .net 4.0:

```
List<Item> cities = new List<City>();
```

Why doesn't that work? Because it must be possible to add arbitrary `Item` s to a `List<Item>`. But, obviously, `cities.Add(new Person());` cannot work (since the "real" (= static) type of `cities` is `List<City>`). Thus, `List<Item>` can never be a supertype of `List<City>`.

You cannot add items to an IEnumerable, which is why there *is* a subtype relationship between `IEnumerable<City>` and `IEnumerable<Item>` (but only in .net 4.0, as mentioned above).

Comment: Hi Heinzi. Thanks for you explanation, which makes sense. The understanding, falsely that I've been under was because we have a super-class of ItemBase that the sub-classes would automatically be defined as such when reflected. A bit of an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
        Type type = ret.GetType();
        Type listType = typeof(IEnumerable<T>);
        if (type == listType || type.IsSubclassOf(listType))
        {
            //
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is wrong:

```
Type classType = className.GetType();
```

This construct will yield the type of `className` which is `String` but not the type whose name is stored in `className`.

A better, more type-safe way would be:

```
public IEnumerable<TItem> InvokeGenericMethod<TItem, TContainer>(...)
    where TItem : ItemBase
    where TContainer : class, new()
{
    TContainer container = new TContainer();
    ...
}
```

**Update:** In case the `TContainer` type is not known statically at the place where `InvokeGenericMethod` is called, have a look on of the the **static** [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7aahsb8.aspx) methods to resolve the actual name from its string name. In the simplest case the [`Type.GetType(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method access an assembly qualified name of your type, e.g. `"MyNamespace.City, MyAssembly"`.

Comment: Hi Ondrej, your proposal will work in a situation where the actual Class is know in it's "purist" form, however, I have a drop down box in my control, that lists the name of entities (classes) as string value. I need to get the underlying type of the associated string from the assembly. I will investigate this further as I feel that your proposed solution might have merit if I change my logic.

Comment: @JadedEric Undestood and updated my answer accordingly. However, if you can change your logic towards a more type-safe solution, possibly avoiding reflection at all, you will typically benefit from it in the future.